# Can I perform this operation faster with regex or something else?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I'm trying to understand a little more `string operations` and `regexes`. 
Here is, for example, a given array of `String` :

```
String [] tab = {"__09_23_HELLO","__89_2_WORLD","900_23_TRY","_34_90_SATELLITE", 
"___23_", "390"};
```

What I want to do here is to keep data ONLY after underscores followed by a letter, and if I can't find it, return `null`. In this example I would get this :

> HELLO WORLD TRY SATELLITE null null

So I wrote this recursive function :

```
public String getName(String string, int i)
{
    if(i == string.length()-1) return null;
    if(string.charAt(i) != '_' || 
      (string.charAt(i) == '_' && !Character.isLetter(string.charAt(i+1)))) 
        return getName(string, i+1);
    else
        return string.substring(i+1);
}
```

And it works well. But as I don't know a lot regexes (and maybe other ways to do ?), I would like to know if I can do that with a regex, and if it will proceed faster with a large amount of data.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can work with a recursive function it'll most definitely be faster to use a different approach:

- Either I would use a loop (similar to your approach but use a loop instead of recursion to increase the counter `i`).
- Or, write it with a regex matching as you suggested.

Which of these two possibilities is faster is not easy to decide, but I would guess that the regex is faster unless your loop code was very clever and as minimal as possible. To find out there is no way around coding up the two approaches and benchmarking it...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I replied to jlordo, I'm afraid that having to reinit a `Matcher` every time I go in the for-loop will make the process slower in the end, if I use a regex, am I wrong?

Comment: I tried to process it iteratively, creating a j for-loop for every tab[i], but it took more time than my recursive loop.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Wanna share that iterative code? As for the `Matcher` initialization: it could well be that the initialization is slower. Especially for short strings/simple patterns (as in your case) a 'hand-drawn' version might be fastest. But as with all performance questions, the only way to know for certain is to implement it and run some benchmarks...

Answer (score 2):

JIT has a hard time optimizing recursive calls (see [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-expensive-method-call-java)), so I try to avoid it where possible. Here's a regex solution (in combination with substring, as you anticipated with your tag).

```
String [] tab = {"__09_23_HELLO","__89_2_WORLD","900_23_TRY","_34_90_SATELLITE",  "___23_", "390"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_[a-zA-Z]");
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tab[i]);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        tab[i] = tab[i].substring(matcher.start() + 1);
    } else {
        tab[i] = null;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tab));
```

Comment: Your example is interesting and thanks a lot for your answer. But assuming we will have to reinit the matcher every time we go in the for-loop, won't it be slower in the end? And will it change something to create the `Matcher matcher;` before the for-loop and only reinit it everytime : `matcher = pattern.matcher(tab[i]);` ?

Comment: @Rob: The matcher has to be reinitialized for every input string. If you don't use the matcher after the loop, putting `Matcher matcher;` before the loop will not change the generated bytecode and will therefor have the same performance. Verified this in another answer a few weeks ago. That's because `Matcher matcher;` doesn't create the matcher, but `pattern.matcher(tab[i]);` does.

Answer (score 2):

Apply regEx for each element in array:

```
/[^_\d\s]+/g
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following implementation (it tranforms values from the original String array):

```
for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index++) {
    String eachString = strings[index];
    int startIndex = eachString.lastIndexOf('_') + 1;
    if (startIndex > 0 && eachString.length() != startIndex && Character.isLetter(eachString.charAt(startIndex))) {
        strings[index] = eachString.substring(startIndex);
    } else {
        strings[index] = null;
    }
}
return strings;
```